# C# Winforms: Populating DataGridView Using BindingSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, ado.net, bindingsource

I have a long query with multiple joins and would like to access fields from all tables.  I have the following ADO.NET code:

```
private void BindData(string sql, List<SqlParameter> parameters = null)
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnStr))
{
    BindingSource dgvBinding = new BindingSource();
    sqlConn.Open();

    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConn))
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add("AdmissionServices");

        sqlDa.Fill(ds, "AdmissionServices");         
        }                    

        dgvBinding.DataSource = ds;
        dgvBinding.DataMember = "AdmissionServices";

        dgvDictatedCases.DataSource = dgvBinding;
    }
}
```

}

Suppose I hadn't added a table to the DataSet object.  I was just wondering why I need to use the overloaded Fill() method which takes a datasource table name (ie. why it doesn't work when I just use the Fill(DataSet) method).  So I'm basically just wondering what scenarios would it be appropriate to use the overloaded Fill() method which takes only the DataSet vs. the one which takes a DataSet object and table name.  In my case, would it have been possible to achieve the same result using the Fill() method which only takes the DataSet?

Comment: `would it have been possible to achieve the same result using the Fill() method which only takes the DataSet?`   Couldn't you have tested that?

Comment: I did test that and it didn't work.  It only works when I specified one of the tables used in the query.  Is it because I'm trying to access fields across multiple tables?  Does the Fill(DataSet) method only work when using a single table?

Comment: Think of a DataSet as a container for multiple DataTables.  `dgvBinding.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];` would have also worked.

Comment: When I used your suggestion with     sqlDa.Fill(ds); I get the following exception: DataMember property 'AdmissionServices' cannot be found in the DataSource.

Comment: Right.  Remove that.

Comment: I read on MSDN that when using a BindingSource (which is what I'm using here) you need to set the DataMember property of the BindingSource object to one of the table names if the datasource contains multiple tables.  But in order to do this I need to use the overloading Fill() method which takes 2 parameters (one being the name of the table).  I wasn't sure if I was correct in this logic or if I'm missing something.

Comment: Not sure what the point of this exercise was.  It sounds like you have working code but are trying to find a different way to accomplish the same thing.  I never quite understood why MS pushed DataSets in their examples when most people just want to use the DataTable.

Comment: Just found a way by using the following line of code:
dgvBinding.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName  in conjunction with sqlDa.fill(ds);

Thanks for your time and help though.  I just need to satisfy my curiosity.